# Finding generators of homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Take the simplicial complex with vertices {a,b,c} and edges {ab, ac, bc}. In other words, a circle. If I build a chain complex, and make the matrix of my differential, I get that the kernel of $C_0\to0$ mod image of $C_1 \to C_0$ is

$\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Z}[a] \times \mathbb{Z}[b] \times \mathbb{Z}[c]} {\mathbb{Z}[a-c] \times \mathbb{Z}[b+c]}$

where the bracket denotes a generator of the group.

Now from basic dimension arguments (and lots of other ways) this has to be just one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. But how can I see or figure out what will be the generator of my quotient group in terms of my other generators?

Comment: Wait, what is $c$?

Comment: I also think your notation is a bit confused. By $\mathbb Z[a]\times\mathbb Z[b]\times\mathbb Z[c]$ do you mean the group generated by $a,b,c$? Because that is not the correct notation for that.

Comment: No, I don't mean the free group on three letters. I realize it's not standard notation, that's why I (tried) to define it. I mean what is written below <a> x <b> x <c> but wanted to make the point that all I'm talking about is copies of Z.

Answer (score 2):

If $c=d$, then $C_0=\langle a,b,c\rangle$ and the image of $C_1$ is $H=\langle a-b,a-c,b-c\rangle$. Since $b-c=(a-c)-(a-b)$, $H$ is actually generated by two elements, $H=\langle a-b,a-c\rangle$.

So the quotient group, $C_0/H$, is generated by $a+H$. That's because $b=a+(-(a-b))\in a+H$, $c=a+(-(a-c))\in a+H$. so $a+H=b+H=c+H$.

Comment: $C_0$ and $C_1$ are abelian free, not free.

Comment: Yeah, didn't mean the notation to imply anything otherwise, @DanielRust. Can you recommend a better notation?

Comment: I guess $\langle a\rangle\oplus \langle b\rangle\oplus \langle c\rangle$ works but it's ugly. I've seen $\mathbb{Z}^{\{a,b,c\}}$ before which isn't too bad.

Comment: Those are both horrible. Anyway, isn't it obvious, since the operator I'm using is $+$, that I'm talking abelian groups? $\langle x,y,z\dots\rangle$ is not specific to free (non)-abelian groups, as far as I know.

Comment: Sure in the context I guess it's fine. I only mentioned it because I could see it being confusing for someone who has maybe only just learned say the Van Kampen theorem where free products are aplenty, and then moving onto homology where this notation might be ambiguous. Not a big deal though.

Comment: $\mathbb Z^S$ is particularly weak when $S$ might be infinite, because the standard meaning is not the same as the free abelian group on $S$. @DanielRust

Comment: My orientation was different so I different generators of the image, but I see what you mean.